# passing extra angular parameter to kendo template

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

How do I pass an extra angular parameter to kendo template? I have the following code:

```
{
    field: "lastName",
    title: "Last Name,<br/> First Name",
    width: "172px",
    attributes: { style: "text-align: center" },
    template: "#= formatNameCE(data) #",
    headerAttributes: { style: "white-space: normal; text-align: center" }
},
```

and I want to pass `$scope.dateRangeFrom` and `$scope.dateRangeTo` to the `formatNameCE` javascript function getting called in the template.

Comment: Can somebody comment on this issue ?

Comment: Can you share some more of your code. I created a quick Plunker and didn't have any issue accessing scope variables from the function called by the template...have a look > http://plnkr.co/edit/f2AWUh6dDlPuBDLfjezI?p=preview